# Search CSV for matching field and use initial date

Tags: python, csv, duplicates

I am attempting to search a CSV file for rows with duplicate device names. The output should record the date from the 1st matching row and also record the date from the last row found. I need some assistance with the logic of removing duplicate device names from the CSV file, whilst also keeping a record of when a device was first and last seen.

```
import time as epoch

# AlertTime, DeviceName, Status
Input = [['14/08/2016 13:00', 'device-A', 'UP'], ['14/08/2016 13:15', 'device-B', 'DOWN'], ['15/08/2016 17:30', 'device-A', 'UP']]

# FirstSeen, LastSeen, DeviceName, Status
Output = []

# Last 48 hours
now = epoch.time()
cutoff = now - (172800)

for i in Input:
    AlertTime = epoch.mktime(epoch.strptime(i[0], '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M'))
    if AlertTime > cutoff:
        Result = [i[0], i[0], i[1], i[2]]
        Output.append(Result)

print(Output)
```

Output (3 entries):

```
[['14/08/2016 13:00', '14/08/2016 13:00', 'device-A', 'UP'], ['14/08/2016 13:15', '14/08/2016 13:15', 'device-B', 'DOWN'], ['15/08/2016 17:30', '15/08/2016 17:30', 'device-A', 'UP']]
```

Wanted Output (2 entries):

```
[['14/08/2016 13:15', '14/08/2016 13:15', 'device-B', 'DOWN'], ['14/08/2016 13:00', '15/08/2016 17:30', 'device-A', 'UP']]
```

Comment: Use dictionary with `device` as key and `(FirstSeen, LastSeen, DeviceName, Status)` as value.

Comment: @VedangMehta maybe you can omitt the 'DeviceName' field since it is already the key? Otherwise, I fully agree.

Comment: @bdvll You're absolutely right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `OrderedDict` to preserve the order that devices are seen in the CSV file. A dictionary is used to automatically remove duplicates.

The following works by attempting to update an existing dictionary entry, if it not already present, Python generates a `KeyError` exception. In this case a new entry can be added with an identical start and end alert time. When updating an entry, the existing `first_seen` is used to update the entry with the latest found `alert_time` and `status`. At the end, the dictionary is parsed to create your required output format:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

# AlertTime, DeviceName, Status
input_data = [['14/08/2016 13:00', 'device-A', 'UP'], ['14/08/2016 13:15', 'device-B', 'DOWN'], ['15/08/2016 17:30', 'device-A', 'UP']]

entries = OrderedDict()

for alert_time, device_name, status in input_data:
    try:
        entries[device_name] = [entries[device_name][0], alert_time, status]
    except KeyError as e:
        entries[device_name] = [alert_time, alert_time, status]

# Convert the dictionary of entries into the required format        
output_data = [[device_name, first_seen, last_seen, status] for device_name, [first_seen, last_seen, status] in entries.items()]

print(output_data)
```

Giving you output as:

```
[['device-A', '14/08/2016 13:00', '15/08/2016 17:30', 'UP'], ['device-B', '14/08/2016 13:15', '14/08/2016 13:15', 'DOWN']]
```

Comment: Thanks Martin, I appreciate your help. I ended up using your approach.

Answer (score 1):

As Vedang Mehta said in the comments, you could use a dict to store the data.

```
    my_dict = {}
    for i in Input:
        AlertTime = epoch.mktime(epoch.strptime(i[0], '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M'))
        if AlertTime > cutoff:
            #if we have seen this device before, update it
            if i[1] in my_dict:
                my_dict[i[1]] = (my_dict[i[1]][0], i[0], i[2])
            #if we haven't seen it, add it
            else:
                my_dict[i[1]] = (i[0],i[0],i[2])
```

After this, all your devices will be stored in `my_dict` containing (`first_seen`, `last_seen` and `status`).

Comment: Thanks bdvll for your effort